# Intel wireless (iwlwifi), Ubuntu 19.04, slow upload speed but only on certain WiFi networks

Tags: networking, wireless, lenovo, iwlwifi

I have a Lenovo IdeaPad S340 running Ubuntu 19.04. It has an Intel dual band wireless adapter using the `iwlwifi` kernel driver.

On one particular WiFi network that uses Cisco access points, I get an OK download speed but a terrible upload speed. I've seen answers to similar questions saying to set the 11n_disable kernel parameter for the `iwlwifi` driver to `11n_disable=1` or `11n_disable=8`, but neither of those worked for me; the former improved my upload speed but cut my download speed in half, and the latter did nothing.

*How can I fix this?*

Comment: What does `cat /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf` tell you?

Comment: I tried disabling power management on the wifi device, didn't help.

Comment: You may also want to see if the problem networks are using TKIP encryption

Comment: Thank your for sharing your knowledge.  An edit of your both Q and A and **+1** to both in return!  **:-)**  Please don't forget to accept your own answer...  **0:-)**  Note: I have no clue why this Q&A attracted a downvote...

Comment: @Jeremy31 I tried enabling software encryption on the kernel module, that didn't help either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I experimented and found that `11n_disable=2` boosted my upload speed by 700%, but at the price of decreasing my download speed by 12%. That's a reasonable trade off when otherwise the upload speed is unusable, but I didn't want to put up with the decreased download speed on WiFi networks whose upload speed was fine without changing the setting. So I wrote a script to check with WiFi network I'm using and adjust the setting accordingly.

Below you can find the script. It needs to be installed as root, mode `0755`, in `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d`. You need to edit the `bad-wifi-network-name` line to properly select which WiFi network(s) you want to use the alternative setting on.

```
#!/bin/bash -e

WHOAMI=$(basename $0)
IFACE="$1"; shift
ACTION="$1"; shift

log() {
    level="$1"; shift

    logger -p daemon.$level -t "$WHOAMI" $@
}

if [ "$ACTION" != "up" ]; then
    log debug ignoring action $ACTION
    exit 0
fi

state=$(cat /sys/module/iwlwifi/parameters/11n_disable)

log notice previous 11n_disable state is $state

if [ "$CONNECTION_ID" = "bad-wifi-network-name" ]; then
    want_state=2
else
    want_state=0
fi

if [ "$state" != "$want_state" ]; then
    log notice reloading iwlwifi with 11n_disable=$want_state
    if ! rmmod iwlmvm iwlwifi; then
        log err rmmod iwlmvm iwlwifi failed
        exit 1
    fi
    if ! modprobe iwlwifi 11n_disable=$want_state; then
        log err modprobe iwlwifi 11n_disable=$want_state failed
        exit 1
    fi
    if ! modprobe iwlmvm; then
        log err modprobe iwlmvm failed
        exit 1
    fi
    log notice finished reloading iwlwifi with 11n_disable=$want_state
else
    log notice 11n_disable is correct, taking no action
fi
```

[For even more detailed information, please go here](https://blog.kamens.us/2019/08/03/mitigating-wifi-upload-speed-issues-on-lenovo-ideapad-s340-running-linux/)
**Disclaimer:** I'm the author of that blog.